# lambda function returning function name

Tags: python, lambda

I have a list where the items are dictionaries. the dictionary values are in unicode format and am trying to compare the unicode values to strings. So, I tried a below lambda function expecting a conversion of unicode to string;

```
a=[(lambda x: x.unicode('UTF-8') ) for i in paid_submissions[0].values()]

print(a)
```

> [ at 0x11335db18>,  at 0x113357d70>,  at 0x113357b90>,  at 0x113357a28>,  at 0x1133b5050>,  at 0x1133b50c8>]

Answer (score 3):

Because you're just returning the lambda object without calling it on anything. If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you would need to call the lambda on `i` like so.

```
a = [(lambda x: x.unicode('UTF-8'))(i) for i in paid_submissions[0].values()]
```

But the `lambda` expression is a waste. This can be more easily (and more efficiently) written as

```
a = [i.unicode('UTF-8') for i in paid_submissions[0].values()]
```

Comment: Thanks , the second syntax without lambda works! However the first syntax with lambda throws an error like;                                                                           TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Comment: @Thirai I had forgotten to pass the `i` in the first one but it should be fixed now. You shouldn't use it anyway -- hence why I'm not used to writing it :)